# Using a dual input sound card with skype

Tags: sound, skype, mac

I am a singing and piano teacher and I need to use Ubuntu to do online lessons. I have my [Focusrite Scarlett 18i18](https://focusrite.com/en/usb-audio-interface/scarlett/scarlett-18i8) USB multichannel mixer-preamp and 2 inputs, one for the vocal microphone and the other for the keyboard. I have an iMac 27, and a MacBook Air.

I use Skype for lessons but the problem is only the input No. 1 works, so I can only use either the voice or the instrument, but not together. So I thought it was a limitation of Skype, but instead a friend of mine manages to use several inputs together easily. Can you help me to lecture and listen to the voice and keyboard at the same time?

Comment: Please keep in mind this site is English-speaking only. You can use online translation tools if necessary, but please try to write in English as well as you can. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Which Ubuntu release do you have installed? 2) Did you install Skype from the Ubuntu repositories (using the Software Center, Synaptec Package Manager, or a CLI command in a terminal) or download it from Microsoft then install it? 3) To test, please install Audacity https://www.audacityteam.org/ from the Ubuntu repositories if you don't already have it. Make a stereo recording while using both inputs, then play it back. Do you hear both channels?

Comment: New versions of Skype seem to work fine with Focusrite. Got a Focusrite 2i4 that did not work with previous versions of Skype in the software depository (same problem as above; did not capture all channels), but  works fine with 8.59.0.77 downloaded directly from skype.com